# Heroku Fail Log Deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, command-line-interface

I'm trying to figure out what the errors are with the application, I can't access 'heroku logs --tail' when I am signed in for heroku in bash and cmd (I'm not sure on the syntax) https://superherodeliverserver.herokuapp.com/. Could you please tell me what the issue is? I can run the github file below using npm install && npm start after cloning it locally. The github file is strictly backend, there are no front-end components.

https://superherodeliverserver.herokuapp.com/

https://github.com/rbirchtree/SuperHerosDeliverserver

FYI, I'm running Windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The CLI command is heroku logs -t -a , so in your case, it
>   would be heroku logs -t -a superherodeliverserver. You can also use the
>   log format--tailand--appbut less typing is always good. If you run the
>   command in the git repo that you push to your Heroku app from you can
>   drop the-a part altogether. The CLI can figure out the app name based
>   off the heroku` git remote.
>
> All Heroku CLI commands have a pretty good help if you are unsure of a
>   command and its options. Just use heroku help

*-This is from Herkou's customer service....*